How to chain mergeMap to get related objects
I'm having problems chaining mergeMap to retrieve related objects. First, I get a listing of users
userService.loadUsers$().pipe(
  mergeMap((users: User[]) => forkJoin(users.map((user: IUser) =>
    combineLatest([
      getRelatedItems(user.uid || '')
    ])

The code above will get me all the desired users if I remove getRelatedItems. getRelatedItems first looks in a cross reference table/collection, and then should return the related items.
const getRelatedItems = (uid: string) => referenceService.loadReferenceItems$({uid})
.pipe(mergeMap((referenceItems) => forkJoin(referenceItems.map((referenceItem) =>
  relatedItemsService.getRelatedItem(referenceItem.relatedItemId || '')
    ))))

The code above gets called but does not return any values. What am I missing?
Explanation addendum:
(an array of items).mergeMap then forkJoin to handle each element
for each element there are multiple properties, with each property being an an array. To get info on each array, I have to do
(array).mergeMap then forkJoin again. This nested forkJoin causes a silent failure within the function. I have confirmed that each statement taken individually does yield the expected results. But I want one function with nested forkJoins. Is that possible?

forkJoin only emits when all the observables complete. Are you sure the observables referenceService.loadReferenceItems$ and relatedItemsService.getRelatedItem() completes? The usage of combineLatest tells me you expect a stream of emissions rather a single emission from getRelatedItems() function.

From what I can see merge map is returning an array of observables, it should return an observable. You can do this forkJoin which wraps the array and executes the inner observables in parallel.
getRelatedItems = (uid: string) =>
  referenceService
    .loadReferenceItems$({ uid })
    .pipe(
      mergeMap((referenceItems) =>
        forkJoin( // <- changed here!
          referenceItems.map((referenceItem) =>
            relatedItemsService.getRelatedItem(
              referenceItem.relatedItemId || ''
            )
          )
        )
      )
    );

